# Hiding data in a django inline formset

Tags: django, django-forms, inline-formset

I am investigating using an inline formset for a django app to populate a 1-many relationship.  I finally got a inline formset working and I noticed that it shows all of the data in a single form.  This is great for one of my users.    However, I have another use case where the user is not allowed to see any of the existing data.  The user can add new data, but is not allowed to see any existing records.

Is it possible to use an inline formset to do this?   Can you have an inline formset hide all existing data rather than display everything in the 1-many relationship?  If so, How?  Any examples?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/326089/codingjoe did you find any solution for the same? I am looking for a similar case where 1 of the row of the inline data is hidden based on a certain condition